# Value greater and change font colour

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I am trying to find two or more Red colour font N's in the spread sheet, where I can turn them into "OT"

I attempted two tries, but failed.

```
a = Sheets("Schedule").Cells(i,j).Value = "N" And Sheets("Schedule").Cells(i,j).Font.Color = vbRed
if a>1 Then Sheets ("Schedule").Cells(i,j).Value - "OT"
End if
```

```
If Sheets("Schedule").Cells(i,j).Value = "N" And 
  Sheets("Schedule").Cells(i,j).Font.Color = vbRed
  if Sheets ("Schedule").Cells(i,j).Value >=2 Then
    Sheets ("Schedule").Cells(i,j).Value - "OT"
  End if 
End if
```

Comment: Are the "N"s the entire content of the cells? Some of your code seems to be missing (where are values for `i` and `j` assigned?). Look into [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) maybe

Comment: `Cells(i,j).Value` is both "N" *and* >2 ?

Comment: I am trying to change 2 or more in same row which is red color into "OT", Example: NNDDD -> OT OT DDD.

Comment: A screenshot would go a long way here...  Also a more-complete set of code to show where `i` and `j` come from.

Comment: Change all instances of red "N" into "OT" in any row having >2 of them ?

Comment: There should be a prize for correctly guessing vague questions. Like a Nobel.